# Why doesn't my HP Deskjet 2514 work?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, hp

I'm new to Ubuntu (using version 12.04 LTS), so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing.  I hope that's the case.  I'm on my second printer, and keep having the same problem.  I'm currently using an HP Deskjet 2514.  The system recognizes the printer and attempts to use a driver for HP series 2500.  When I try to print a test page, though, I get to "Idle - Rendering completed" and the page never prints.

From what I can tell, I've got HPLIP installed, but I don't know if there's something I need to do that I'm not doing.  From what I've read, it seems that the 2514 should be supported, but it's not working.

Incidentally, my first try was with a Canon Pixma MG2520, and it did exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try with installing following packages :

```
sudo apt-get install hp-ppd hpijs hpijs-ppds hplip hplip-cups hplip-data hplip-dbg hplip-doc hplip-gui printer-driver-postscript-hp djtools
```

You can find some Ubuntu printer drivers [Here](http://allfreeubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-find-drivers-for-external.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hp-ppd
```

For more detail go to https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip and select *Ubuntu* as the Linux distribution.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/390064/790920

Comment: @abu_bua: Not exactly.