# Hp Deskjet 1010 printers drivers for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, hp

I can't installs drivers from Hp site. I can't install hp lip 3.13.11 run. I don't find support tech and can't run the hp Cd printer drivers on my computer with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: hplip comes already installed in Ubuntu, what is exactly your issue? did you tried to just plug in your printer?

Answer (score 1):

HPLIP drivers are available in Main Ubuntu Repository which are compatible with older Ubuntu versions. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/390064/224082) answer to install them properly.